# Issue using Flask-Assets to compile less files

Tags: python, flask, less, webassets, flask-assets

I'm currently trying to set up a Flask web app, and trying to use `Flask-Assets` to compile my less files into minified css.

Here is my assets.py file that creates the bundle.

```
from flask_assets import Bundle

common_css = Bundle(
    'vendor/less/theme.less',
    filters='less',
    output='static/css/common.css',
    )
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In the `webassets` documentation for the [less filter](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/webassets/builtin_filters.html#less), it says that:

```
This depends on the NodeJS implementation of less, installable via npm. To use the old Ruby-based version (implemented in the 1.x Ruby gem), see Less.

...

LESS_BIN (binary)
    Path to the less executable used to compile source files. By default, the filter will attempt to run lessc via the system path.
```

I installed `less` using `$ npm install less`, but for some reason it looks like `webassets` can't use it.

When I try to use different filters, then `webassets` can successfully create the bundle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`npm install` installs packages in current directory by default (you should be able to find `node_modules` directory there). You have two choices:

1. Install `lessc` globally:

   ```
   $ npm install -g less
   ```

   This way webassets will be able to find it itself.
2. Provide a full path to `lessc` executable:

   ```py
   assets = Environment(app)
   assets.config['less_bin'] = '/path/to/lessc'
   ```

   The path should be `<some_directory>/node_modules/.bin/lessc`.

Comment: Note that this only worked for me when I used the FULL PATH to lessc and not the path relative to my project.